# What Name from Event Library?

Tags: extended-events

I'm new in SQL Server's extended events and you can create your own session and select your own name in Event library.

From your experience, what name from event library have you selected in order to faciliate your work or similar?

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Brent Ozar](https://www.brentozar.com/extended-events/) has a good list of use cases for extended events and how to implement them.

More specifically Erik Darling also released a procedure [sp_HumanEvents: Humanizing Extended Events](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/sp_humanevents/sp_humanevents-humanizing-extended-events/) that simplifies monitoring extended events for the usual use cases.